# Very low beta coefficients, but cannot understand why

Tags: logistic, statistical-significance

I am running a logistic regression of marital status on age, age^2, religion importance, gender, race, education level, income, hours worked and residence area, using data from NLS.

After doing all the work of data cleaning I am running a logistic regression and even after converting the log odds into odds I get very small coefficients. Is there any way to rescue the model? Maybe drop some variables, although all of them seem important. I am not quite sure of the reason, but I assume that this is mainly due to the many categorical variables that I have, only age income and hours worked are continuous.

I cannot really think of any reason to convincingly argue about the low values of the coefficients. None of them are significant as well.

Comment: I want to see how low. Can you post your model summary?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `degree` is entered into the model as an interval variable, while it is an ordered categorical one, and needs to be treated as one. The simplest way is to transform it into a Factor (`as.factor(degree)`). Without this transformation, the interpretation means that each increase in one(1) unit of degree will increase the odds of being married (if that is the dependent variable) by a factor of 1.108, for men, holding the other variables constant. You shouldn't interpret MA like this though. This would have been OK only if this was a count or continuous variable. What the coefficient means now, is the *average* difference in odds between each category pairs, but without set intervals, the model assumes that the interval is 1 (0-to-1, 1-to-2, etc..).

Answer (score 0):

I panicked too fast. Turns out the log odds can be very low, but after taking the e-function things look normal. This is my output from R:

```
Call:
glm(formula = married ~ Female + age + Black + Hispanic + Msa + 
    rel_pref + yinc + hrs_wrkd + degree + degree_fem, family = binomial(link = logit), 
    data = nlsy2)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.4025  -1.0825   0.4939   1.0455   2.1968  

Coefficients:
               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  -5.585e+00  5.717e-01  -9.768  < 2e-16 ***
Female        4.595e-01  9.803e-02   4.687 2.77e-06 ***
age           1.691e-01  1.830e-02   9.241  < 2e-16 ***
BlackTRUE    -1.278e+00  6.716e-02 -19.029  < 2e-16 ***
HispanicTRUE -2.943e-01  6.510e-02  -4.520 6.18e-06 ***
Msa          -5.146e-01  5.171e-02  -9.952  < 2e-16 ***
rel_pref      5.254e-01  5.556e-02   9.457  < 2e-16 ***
yinc          1.007e-05  1.176e-06   8.562  < 2e-16 ***
hrs_wrkd      2.689e-05  2.577e-05   1.044   0.2967    
degree        1.026e-01  4.353e-02   2.356   0.0185 *  
degree_fem   -3.317e-02  5.766e-02  -0.575   0.5651    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 9851.6  on 7106  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 8945.5  on 7096  degrees of freedom
AIC: 8967.5

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4

> exp(coef(married1))
 (Intercept)       Female          age    BlackTRUE HispanicTRUE          Msa     rel_pref         yinc     hrs_wrkd 
 0.003755289  1.583298625  1.184297429  0.278581731  0.745073838  0.597713776  1.691114349  1.000010068  1.000026891 
      degree   degree_fem 
 1.108001765  0.967370363
```

I am googling like crazy on the topic of predicting marital status, but cannot find any previous work on it. Seems like people didn't think it is a good idea to run a model like this. If you have any suggestions on how this model can be improved, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: You can answer your own question if you have a clear answer.  But I think you are mainly asking more questions.

Comment: I am actually wondering how I could interpret the variable degree. So far degree=0 is no education, degree=1 is a High School degree, degree=2 is a BA and degree=3 is MA. Question1: How would I interpret the odds for someone with an MA? Question2: Do you see any difficulty in running a regression on a categorical variable grouped this way vs. creating a dummy for each degree and run a logistic regression on each of the degree dummies?

Comment: Then formulate a new question.

Comment: @Michael Chernick: There are 2 questions I am asking already.

Comment: besides consolidating this with the question, can you tell us what exactly is marital status? (what are the categories, how was it constructed..). Thanks